# How fix this: on logcat -->> error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg??

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, android-fragmentactivity, android-logcat

I have a problem:

```
error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
```

It's shown when I click navdraw icon. Anybody can help me??

This is errors on logcat:

```
04-20 01:42:11.240: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.251: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.251: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.280: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.280: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.280: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.311: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.311: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
04-20 01:42:11.311: E/SoundPool(639): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code please?

Comment: I'm confused to show the relevant code, before I make the navigation drawer, when I click on one of its menu will appear content with fragment tabs with a swipe, but when I click the navigation menu it does not appear his

Comment: You can't access the file system - you must have root access.

Comment: should I be rooting it? how? I'm using the emulator

Answer (score 12):

This is Android emulator issue. To workaround it just disable all sounds in Android settings (particularly "Touch sounds").

Comment: And how d you do that?

Comment: Depends on the Android version but for me it was `Apps => Settings => Device => Sound => System  => Touch Sound`

Answer (score 2):

For me,

I just closed the emulator and started again, its worked.